What are the modulus and the argument of a complex number equals to its own logarithm?
I’m looking for a complex number $z=re^{i\theta}$ equals to its own logarithm, i.e such that
\begin{equation}
z= \log z
\end{equation}
If so, what relations should satisfy the modulus $\vert z \vert=r$ and $\theta$ ?
For example, how can I write $\theta$ in terms of an inverse tangent ?
Many thanks for any help.

Given $z=\log z$, then you have $r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) = \log(re^{i\theta})=\log(r)+i\theta$.
Comparing the imaginary and real parts, you have: $r\cos\theta = \log r$, $r\sin\theta = \theta$.
You can simplify these equations if you further want to know the relations between $r$ and $\theta$.

Need $~\displaystyle \left[ ~\log(r) ~\right]^2 + \theta^2 = r^2.$  You might also mention that the whole question is meaningless unless some arbitrary convention is adopted that specifies the half-open interval of length $~2\pi~$ which will contain the argument to $~z.~$  Without such a convention, the expression $~\log(z)~$ refers to a set of numbers, rather than a specific value, so the equation $~z = \log(z)~$ might reasonably be construed to be gibberish.

Re last comment, alternatively, one could construe the equation $~z = \log(z)~$ to represent that there exists some element in the set of numbers that represents $~\log(z)~$ such that $~z~$ equals this element.

user 2661923: Thank you. So I need to specify $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi / 2$ for some set of valeurs of $r$.  And  $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$ for  other set of valeurs of $r$. Why $r=((ln r)^2+\theta^2)^{1/2}$ ?This is the  important point I don’t understand.

Naga Sai Prajith: Thank you for your help.

We have $r\cos\theta=\log r$ and $r\sin\theta=\theta \implies r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=(\log r)^2 + \theta ^ 2$.
As $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, we have this relation.
